# Search for a keyword across post types in a Gutenberg component

Tags: javascript, block-editor, rest-api, array

In a Gutenberg component I'm developing, I have a function that searches for a keyword across multiple post types specified in a constant:

```
const postTypes = [ 'posts', 'pages', 'portfolio' ];

const onSearchStringChange = ( keyword ) => {
    Promise.all( postTypes.map( postType => apiFetch( {
        path: `/wp/v2/${ postType }?search=${ keyword }`,
    } ) ) ).then( ( results ) => {
        console.log( results.reduce( ( result, final ) => [...final, ...result], [] ) );
    } )
};
```

The function works as expected and returns an array of results.

Instead of using a static array of post types, I'd like to get the viewable post types (minus the `attachment` post type) of a site via a function. This is what I'm using:

```
const postTypes = useSelect( ( select ) => {
    const { getPostTypes } = select( 'core' );
    const excludedPostTypes = [ 'attachment' ];
    const filteredPostTypes = getPostTypes( { per_page: -1 } )?.filter(
        ( { viewable, slug } ) => viewable && ! excludedPostTypes.includes( slug )
    );
    const result = ( filteredPostTypes || [] ).map( ( { slug } ) => slug );
    return result;
}, [] );
```

The function also works as expected and I get an array of slugs of all viewable post types minus `attachment`.

But, if I pass the resulting array to the `onSearchStringChange` function I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { code: "rest_no_route", message: "No route was found matching the URL and request method.", data: {…} }
​code: "rest_no_route"
​data: Object { status: 404 }
​message: "No route was found matching the URL and request method."
​<prototype>: Object { … }
```

I suppose that the post types array is not fully resolved at the time of calling the `onSearchStringChange` function. Even if I do a `postTypes.length > 0` check before the `apiFetch` I get the same error.

So, my question is: how can I make sure that the post types array is fully resolved when calling `onSearchStringChange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing multiple `apiFetch` calls for each post type, a more optimal solution to make a search across multiple post types is to use the WP REST API `search` endpoint, which I didn't know it existed until now. The downside is that you don't get the full post objects using this endpoint, but if you only need the post id, title, url and type, it's ok:

```
const postTypes = useSelect( ( select ) => {
    const { getPostTypes } = select( 'core' );
    const excludedPostTypes = [ 'attachment' ];
    const filteredPostTypes = getPostTypes( { per_page: -1 } )?.filter(
        ( { viewable, slug } ) => viewable && ! excludedPostTypes.includes( slug )
    );
    const result = ( filteredPostTypes || [] ).map( ( { slug } ) => slug );
    return result;
}, [] );

const onSearchStringChange = ( keyword ) => {
    if ( postTypes.length > 0 ) {
        apiFetch( {
            path: `/wp/v2/search?search=${ keyword }&type=post&subtype=${ postTypes.join() }`,
        } ).then( ( results ) => {
            console.log( results );
        } )
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering myself for the benefit of others. I was passing an array of post type slugs to `apiFetch` instead of passing an array with their `rest_base` parameter. So, the correct function should be:

```
const postTypes = useSelect( ( select ) => {
    const { getPostTypes } = select( 'core' );
    const excludedPostTypes = [ 'attachment' ];
    const filteredPostTypes = getPostTypes( { per_page: -1 } )?.filter(
        ( { viewable, slug } ) => viewable && ! excludedPostTypes.includes( slug )
    );
    const result = ( filteredPostTypes || [] ).map( ( { rest_base } ) => rest_base );
    return result;
}, [] );
```

Comment: This is indeed a helpful answer +1